# Number 9 in lower right hand corner - what does it mean?

Tags: windows

Suddenly this icon appeared - simply the number 9 on a black background. It does not open or is not labelled by passing the mouse over it? Any ideas?
Could not find that icon in my Programs list.

Comment: upload a screenshot of the icon, so we have a better idea...

Answer (score 11):

If you are using a Dell laptop, it indicates the number lock is on. Use <kbd>NumLock</kbd> to turn it off (may or may not need the <kbd>Fn</kbd> combo).

Comment: You got it - thanks. Worried it might indicate something more serious. Appreciate your time to respond!

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept it as your answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: That is an annoying feature.

Answer (score 0):

Grab [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and use the Windows Process finder (looks like a target) to determine which/what process it is.